# Android: Video Encoding H.264 and Setting Framerate Not Working

Tags: android, video-encoding, h.264, frame-rate

I have an HTC MyTouch 3G Slide (Android 2.1, API level 7). I am trying to write a program to record 320x240 h.264 video at 15fps, but I have 2 major problems. I would be grateful for a solution to either issue. Here is what I am doing:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/test.mp4");
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSizeInBytes);
mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();
```

**Problem 1)** H263 and MPEG_4_SP work fine, but H264 does not. On the call to prepare(), the logcat is filled with the errors below:

```
E/PackageInstallationReceiver(  209): Remove /data/local/tmp/com.helios.apk Fail!
E/mm-camera 7x-vfe( 2496): Received VFE start ACK!!! This is a user preview start.
E/audio_input( 2496): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
E/audio_input( 2496): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
E/CameraInput( 2496): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
E/CameraInput( 2496): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
E/PVOMXEncNode( 2496): PVMFOMXEncNode-Audio_AMRNB::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.PV.amrencnb handle 
E/PVOMXEncNode( 2496): PVMFOMXEncNode-Video_AVC::DoPrepare(): Cannot get component OMX.PV.avcenc handle, try another component if available
E/AuthorDriver( 2496): Command 13 completed with error -17
E/MediaRecorder( 3221): prepare failed: -17
E/Helios  ( 3221): prepare failed.
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221): java.lang.RuntimeException: unlock failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.hardware.Camera.unlock(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.helios.ActivityLauncher.startRecording(ActivityLauncher.java:268)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.helios.ActivityLauncher.onLongClick(ActivityLauncher.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.helios.ActivityLauncher.onClick(ActivityLauncher.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2361)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4176)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3706)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2068)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1680)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1707)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4702)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3221):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/dalvikvm( 3221): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
E/JavaBinder(   78): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/ActivityManager(   78): fail to set top app changed!
E/audio_input( 2496): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
E/audio_input( 2496): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
E/CameraInput( 2496): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
E/CameraInput( 2496): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
E/CameraService( 2496): getClientFromCookie: client appears to have died
E/mm-camera( 2496): +++ DELETING LEAKED MEMORY AT 0x33f48 (2 REMAINING)
E/mm-camera( 2496):      6 0xa942ba5c
E/mm-camera( 2496):      5 0xa940bfc2
E/mm-camera( 2496):      4 0xa940d774
E/mm-camera( 2496):      3 0xa940d28a
E/mm-camera( 2496):      2 0xafe100c4
E/mm-camera( 2496):      1 0xafe0fb98
E/mm-camera( 2496): +++ DELETING LEAKED MEMORY AT 0x20dc8 (1 REMAINING)
E/mm-camera( 2496):      6 0xa942ba5c
E/mm-camera( 2496):      5 0xa940bfc2
E/mm-camera( 2496):      4 0xa940d774
E/mm-camera( 2496):      3 0xa940d28a
E/mm-camera( 2496):      2 0xafe100c4
E/mm-camera( 2496):      1 0xafe0fb98
```

When using H.263 (which works), the error log only contains:

```
E/CameraInput(   58): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
E/CameraInput(   58): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
E/PVOMXEncNode(   58): PVMFOMXEncNode-Audio_AMRNB::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.PV.amrencnb handle 
E/OMXVenc (   58): component_init::359 Initializing component OMX.qcom.video.encoder.h263
E/PVOMXEncNode(   58): PVMFOMXEncNode-Video_H263::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.qcom.video.encoder.h263 handle 
E/OMXVenc (   58): set_parameter::1104 set_parameter : output buffer size = 76800
E/OMXVenc (   58): set_parameter::1104 set_parameter : output buffer size = 76800
E/OMXVenc (   58): get_parameter::1007 unsupported index 100663301
E/OMXVenc (   58): set_parameter::1240 unsupported index 100663301
E/OMXVenc (   58): get_parameter::1007 unsupported index 100663302
E/OMXVenc (   58): set_parameter::1240 unsupported index 100663302
E/OMXVenc (   58): send_command::758 attempt to move to new state 2
E/OMXVenc (   58): Setting OMX_Video_ControlRateVariable
E/OMXVenc (   58): use_buffer::1437 client allocated input buffer for component 115200, address= 0x98228
E/OMXVenc (   58): use_buffer::1437 client allocated input buffer for component 115200, address= 0x98218
E/OMXVenc (   58): use_buffer::1437 client allocated input buffer for component 115200, address= 0x98208
E/OMXVenc (   58): use_buffer::1437 client allocated input buffer for component 115200, address= 0x981f8
E/OMXVenc (   58): allocate_buffer::1577 Attempt to allocate buffer of 76800 bytes for OUTPUT PORT
E/OMXVenc (   58): allocate_buffer::1577 Attempt to allocate buffer of 76800 bytes for OUTPUT PORT
E/OMXVenc (   58): allocate_buffer::1577 Attempt to allocate buffer of 76800 bytes for OUTPUT PORT
E/OMXVenc (   58): allocate_buffer::1577 Attempt to allocate buffer of 76800 bytes for OUTPUT PORT
E/OMXVenc (   58): send_command::758 attempt to move to new state 2
E/OMXVenc (   58): process_state_change::2580 Req to Move to Idle: Call venc_stop
E/VENC    (   58): venc_stop::1150 Received command VENC_CMD_STOP
E/VENC_DRV(   58): Reset_HW::344 adsp_rtos_disable
E/OMXVenc (   58): process_DL_status::2737 got DL status for VENC_CMD_STOP
E/OMXVenc (   58): process_DL_status::2809 encoder already moves to idle state. call event handler now
E/OMXVenc (   58): send_command::758 attempt to move to new state 1
E/audio_input(   58): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
E/audio_input(   58): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
E/CameraInput(   58): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
E/CameraInput(   58): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
E/QCOmxcore(   58): OMXCORE API :  Free Handle 93b2c
E/VENC    (   58): venci_process_command_unload::2408 Encoder time taken to Exit from Stop command: 76
E/OMXVenc (   58): component_deinit::2033 deinitializing component...
E/OMXVenc (   58): component_deinit::2108 Encoder has exited
E/QCOmxcore(   58):  Unloading the dynamic library for OMX.qcom.video.encoder.h263
E/mm-camera(   58): +++ DELETING LEAKED MEMORY AT 0x3fe78 (2 REMAINING)
E/mm-camera(   58):      6 0xa942ba5c
E/mm-camera(   58):      5 0xa940bfc2
E/mm-camera(   58):      4 0xa940d774
E/mm-camera(   58):      3 0xa940d28a
E/mm-camera(   58):      2 0xafe100c4
E/mm-camera(   58):      1 0xafe0fb98
E/mm-camera(   58): +++ DELETING LEAKED MEMORY AT 0x2dd00 (1 REMAINING)
E/mm-camera(   58):      6 0xa942ba5c
E/mm-camera(   58):      5 0xa940bfc2
E/mm-camera(   58):      4 0xa940d774
E/mm-camera(   58):      3 0xa940d28a
E/mm-camera(   58):      2 0xafe100c4
E/mm-camera(   58):      1 0xafe0fb98
```

**Problem 2)** Although I am explicitly setting the framerate to 15fps, post-analysis of the clips shows strange framerates like 21.xx or 25.xx fps.

Why might H264 not be working, and why might MediaRecorder not be obeying my requested frame rate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to normally save in h263 and h264 using builtin camera app?

Comment: The built-in camera app gives me h263 and mpeg4sp as options. I'm getting the idea that janin (below) is right... and that my device doesn't support h264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H.264 is only supported in [Android 3.0+](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Check the [CamcorderProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html) to know which encoding profiles your device supports.

Comment: The documentation included with MediaRecorder in Eclipse for H264 states it's API 3+, not Android 3.0+

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1)
Cannot get component OMX.PV.avcenc handle
your handset is not support H.264 encode.